# Dealing with "Not Found" in an Object Oriented REST CRUD system

Tags: rest, architecture, crud, restful-architecture

This question falls more into the theory side of things rather than a direct issue with some code I am writing.

**What am I looking for?**

I have a common problem which I am sure many people face daily and I would like to establish opinions and then answers. I am not sure if there is a correct answer or not but perhaps we'll get somewhere close.

**The Problem.**

I am creating a RESTful API. This API speaks to many different types of subsystem, DB's third party API's, SOAP etc...

In order for our code to be easy to read, maintain and test we are trying to come up with a consistent way of building our system. The problem we have is that for server errors and downstream errors we generate an exception which bubbles up and presents itself as either a HTTP 500/502 response with some meaningful message. The way we have implemented this is fine and I don't have an issue with it, however, currently we are generating HTTP 404's in exactly the same way, and this is a major problem because a 404 is not exception worthy.

So, what strategies do you use to deal with this kind of situation? Do you have a common architecture which you have successfully implemented to deal with this without polluting your core domain with entity or representation logic? What do you return from your repository layer so that your domain layer can continue to function correctly irrespective of whether there is data there or not?

**Some possible solutions I am thinking about**

- Use of a NullObject pattern
- Ensure there is always an id I can have a null value for

Whatever I do needs to be really easy to read and follow.

Thanks in advance for any help, advice or opinions you provide.

Answer (score 2):

Why is a 404 not exception worthy?  The user asked for something that they expect to be there, and it isn't.  That is an exception.  You cannot proceed with the code as designed.

Comment: A 404 isn't exception worthy because it isn't a true system failure. The data not being there is in fact a good response because it gives knowledge of the existence of data for a given parameter or query. Other situations such as couldn't connect to downstream system is absolutely exception worthy. I want to dissociate between system errors(5xx's) and a 404. A 5xx should cause my system to stop processing the request. A 404 should not stop the system processing the request. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I understand the logic, but being this pedantic about exceptions is not valuable.  Along this logic chain, every piece of data should be completely sanitized and even "pre committed" to the database, to make sure there isn't a reason it can't be pushed to the database.  The only true "system" errors end up being unknowable states (like servers down).  You can treat exceptions this way, but you are discarding a large amount of the value of checked exceptions.  A 404 is a failure of business logic, not of systems.  You shouldn't have gotten to this point, and it is exceptional that you did.

Comment: I can see what you are saying here. I suppose there is a deeper question about the appropriateness of exceptions for different scenarios but that's probably off question. As it happens at the moment we have implemented 404's using exceptions simply because we haven't discovered a better way of dealing with this yet. I take your point about failed business logic, and certainly from a navigable REST perspective we shouldn't be exposing links which can't be found. I'm going to think some more about this and I'd be interested in further thoughts you have on this.